# How to Order by in Nested Query?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a table like this :

`MY_TABLE`

```
Id   Name  Brand   Date 
--   ----  -----   ------
1    ABC    1      18-09-2019
2    XYZ    1      19-09-2019
3    MNO    1      18-09-2019
4    ABC    1      19-09-2019
5    PQR    2      17-06-2020
6    MNO    1      19-03-2019
7    ABC    2      19-09-2019
```

I want to write a query in such a way that first i need to sort based on `Date`. Based on that result i have to sort `count(Name)` for a `brand`.Like this

```
ID    Name   Count(Name)   Brand   date
---   ----   ----------   ------   -----
1      ABC      2            1      19-09-2019
2      XYZ      1            1      19-09-2019  // Eventhough count is less it came second because 19-09-2019 is latest than 19-03-2019
3      MNO      2            1      18-09-2019
```

Comment: Where's the `PQR` row?

Comment: @TheImpaler PQR row is for brand =2 ,query has written to get only for brand=1. Check my where condition.

Comment: Why `19-03-2019` for MNO?

Comment: @forpas OOps!. Thats typo. Corrected!

Comment: @VinayHegde see my answer

Comment: How are you getting ID=2 for the MNO row in your desired output?

Comment: @forpas Sry..By mistake it was clicked while browsing and at the same time my internet went down. I corrected now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `group by name` and aggregate:

```
select
  name,
  count(*) counter,
  max(brand) brand,
  max(trunc(datee)) maxdate
from my_table
where brand = 1
group by name
order by maxdate desc, counter desc
```

I used `trunc(datee)` because your dates (as we found out) contain a time part.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4f920f6d1b2b08d3bef933e45c482408).
Results:

```
> NAME | COUNTER | BRAND | MAXDATE  
> :--- | ------: | ----: | :--------
> ABC  |       2 |     1 | 19-SEP-19
> XYZ  |       1 |     1 | 19-SEP-19
> MNO  |       2 |     1 | 18-SEP-19
```

Comment: Its sorting only by date . But my question is after sorting by date i want to sort by count , like if i have two names for the same date , i want to show a name which is having count highest for that date. That's not happening in your query.

Comment: Not working. I am getting same result . Its not sorting on counter.

Comment: Are you sure? Did you add ..., count(*) desc in the ORDER BY clause? This is standard SQL.

Comment: Can you post the actual code that you are executing?

Answer (score 1):

You have to first create the count using a group by and then sort by using order by which supports multiple fields (comma separated). And once you give an alias to the column with the count you an use this alias in the order by:

```
select name, brand, min(date), count(name) as NumRecords, min(id) as id
from my_table
group by name, brand
order by date, NumRecords
```

I added the min(id) because it seems that you are trying to show the minimum id.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to select one row per name/brand pair based on the highest count on the most recent date:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name, brand order by date desc, count desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: @VinayHegde . . . This is actually standard SQL and should work in any databases (well, `count` might be a reserved word in some databases).

Comment: @VinayHegde . . . https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
  SELECT MIN(ID),  Name,   
   Count(Name),   Brand,  MIN(date) as 
    Date_MIN
   From Table where Brand =1 Group by 
   Brand,Name 
   Order by Date_MIN desc,Count(Name) 
   Desc;
  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT name, COUNT(*) BrandCount, MAX(brand) brand, date from my_table 
ORDER BY date

You may use [ ASC | DESC ] in the end depending upon requirement.
Similar [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093743/how-to-format-and-sort-a-date-in-oracle).

Hope it sorts